# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, how to set my instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to search by keywords some titles, I need help to set my instances variables tutos.... ( It seems that I need two instances @tutos... but I don't know how to do?

I tried:
 `@tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category) || Tuto.search(params[:search])` but I have the same error...
I have `undefined method each' for nil:NilClass` even though I have the instance variable set... thanks for your help

**my controller**

```
class TutosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_tuto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]


  def index
    @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
    keyword_search
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def keyword_search
    @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search])
  end

  def show
    @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.all
  end

  def new
    @tuto = Tuto.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create

    @tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)
    @tuto.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.save
        flash[:success] = "Test"
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.update(tuto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @tuto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tutos_url, notice: 'Tuto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def upvote
    @tuto.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end


  private


    def set_tuto
      @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tuto_params
      params.require(:tuto).permit(:title, :content, :id, :user_id, :category_id)
    end
end
```

**my index**

```
.container
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      h1.text-gray Tutorials 
      h4 Search by Title
      =form_tag tutos_path, :method => 'get' do 
        =text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
        =submit_tag "Search", class:'btn btn-default'

        = form_tag '/tutos', method: 'get' do
          select[name="category.id"]
            - @categories.each do |category|
              |  <option value="
              = category.id
              | ">
              = category.name
          input[type="submit" value="Search", class="btn btn-default"]

    .col-xs-12
      -if user_signed_in?
        = link_to "Create a tuto", new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-success"
      br
      br    


#tutos.transitions-enabled
  -@tutos.each do |tuto|
    .box.panel-default
      = link_to image_tag(image_by_category(tuto.category.try(:name))), tuto_path(tuto)


      h3 = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto), class:"title-link"     
      h6 
        | Created by:
        span<>
        = tuto.user.full_name
      br
      span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      span<>
      = tuto.get_upvotes.size
      br
      br
```

**tuto model**

```
class Tuto < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category_id, presence: true


  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(["title LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `index` like this. you don't need `keyword_search`.

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search]).includes(:user, :category)
  else
    @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
  end
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def index
    @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
    keyword_search // **Here you are overriding @tutos... First have no meaning always**
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def keyword_search
    @tutos = Tuto.search(params[:search])
  end
```

2 ->

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(["title LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

It will give nil if searched data is not available, so you should handle this.. otherwise each with nil occurs